# Table size using JPA query language

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

Using JPA query language, how do I determine the size (number of rows) in an entity (table)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the count aggregate function:

```
EntityManager em = ...
Query q = em.createQuery ("SELECT count(x) FROM Magazine x");
Number result = (Number) q.getSingleResult ();
```